# Getting Error "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden" when screen scraping using HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, screen-scraping, httpwebresponse, http-status-code-403

We have a tool which checks if a given URL is a live URL. If a given url is live another part of our software can screen scrap the content from it.

This is my code for checking if a url is live

```
    public static bool IsLiveUrl(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.6) Gecko/20060728 Firefox/1.5";
        webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        WebResponse webResponse;
        try
        {
            webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This code works perfectly but for a particular site hosted on apache i am getting a web exception with following message. "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden"
On further inspection i found the following details in the WebException object

Status="ProtocolError"
StatusDescription="Bad Behaviour"

This is the request header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.6) Gecko/20060728 Firefox/1.5
Host: scenicspares.co.uk
Connection: Keep-Alive"

This is the response header "Keep-Alive: timeout=4, max=512
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 13 Jan 2011 10:29:36 GMT
Server: Apache"

I extracted these headers using a watch in vs2008. The frame work in use is 3.5.

Answer (score 13):

It turned out that all i needed to do was following

```
            webRequest.Accept = "*/*";
            webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

and it was fixed.

Comment: Hello @syed, I face the same problem, and already add the .Accept code, but I still got this error. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Got it, I must add these three lines, ` webRequest.Method = "GET";
            webRequest.UserAgent = "Foo";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/html";` Different server may require different setup

Comment: Thanks swdev. Your tip seems to resolve the problem with some wikipedia pages.

Comment: @swdev: Thanks. I was missing the webRequest.UserAgent line.

Comment: Just seeing this page again, and I am happy that some fellows out there gain advantage of my tips :)

Comment: For me didn't help

Comment: Spot on thanks mate! Worked like a charm. Why this is not an answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are quite a lot of similar problems that depend on server application. In my particular case see: [The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735042/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden/27882588#27882588)

Answer (score 0):

I **fixed** it for my web **scraping** app after facing this issue for day long, hope it might help others:

```
    public static string GetPageContent(string url)
    {
        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer; // after Create() method
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true; //  should be true
        request.UserAgent= ".NET Framework Test Client"; // should not be null

        var responseStr = string.Empty;
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            responseStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
        }
        return responseStr;
    }
```