# How to download image from URL through a proxy using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, image

I'm trying to download PNG images to file but I'm doing it through my company network proxy.  I found this [bit of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797485/how-to-download-image-from-url-using-c-sharp) to download PNG images.  Here's the code:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) 
{
    byte [] data = webClient.DownloadData("https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10555140_10201501435212873_1318258071_n.jpg?oh=97ebc03895b7acee9aebbde7d6b002bf&oe=53C9ABB0&__gda__=1405685729_110e04e71d9");

   using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data)) 
   {
       using (var yourImage = Image.FromStream(mem)) 
       { 
          // If you want it as Png
           yourImage.Save("path_to_your_file.png", ImageFormat.Png) ; 
       }
   } 

}
```

I'm using this bit of code to get passed the proxy, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the code mentioned above to download the images:

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.Proxy = new WebProxy(PROXY_URL, true);
clientHandler.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(PROXY_UID, PROXY_PWD, PROXY_DMN);
var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
var result = client.GetStreamAsync(url).Result;
```

I think I'm close.  What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.Proxy = new WebProxy(PROXY_URL, true);
clientHandler.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(PROXY_UID, PROXY_PWD, PROXY_DMN);
var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
var stream = client.GetStreamAsync(url).Result;
using (var yourImage = Image.FromStream(stream)) 
{ 
  // If you want it as Png
   yourImage.Save("path_to_your_file.png", ImageFormat.Png) ; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The WebClient object in your using statement also has the Proxy property. You only need to include these lines directly inside your using statement:

```
webClient.Proxy = new WebProxy(PROXY_URL, true);
webClient.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(PROXY_UID, PROXY_PWD, PROXY_DMN);
```

Note that I haven't tried this code. Just making an observation.

Answer (score 0):

.net Framework allows PictureBox Control to Load Images from url

So Simply Load Image in Picture Box

and Save image in Laod Complete Event

`pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "PROXY_URL;`

```
void pictureBox1_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
   pictureBox1.Image.Save(destination);
}
```