# Deserializing Json data with Xamarin.Forms C#

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

I have a problem I just can't seem to wrap my head around. I'm new to Xamarin.Forms (and C#) and I'm trying to deserialize Json data that I requested from Giphy.com. Here's my code:

```
var uri = new Uri(string.Format ("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + SearchText + "&api_key=1234&limit=5", string.Empty));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                try
                {
                    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                    string ImageUrl = data["url"].Value<string>();



                    Giphy = _giphyService.GetGiphyImageUrl(ImageUrl);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Message: " + e);
                }

            }
```

My application doesn't give an error until I'm trying to use the ImageUrl string. The error tells me that ImageUrl is empty, while the "url" key does exist in my Json data. I tested the same code with a different Json string and this worked fine.

This is the example Json data that does work:

```
string json = "{ \"Atlantic/Canary\": \"GMT Standard Time\", \"Europe/Lisbon\": \"GMT Standard Time\", \"Antarctica/Mawson\": \"West Asia Standard Time\", \"Etc/GMT+3\": \"SA Eastern Standard Time\", \"Etc/GMT+2\": \"UTC-02\", \"Etc/GMT+1\": \"Cape Verde Standard Time\", \"Etc/GMT+7\": \"US Mountain Standard Time\", \"Etc/GMT+6\": \"Central America Standard Time\", \"Etc/GMT+5\": \"SA Pacific Standard Time\", \"Etc/GMT+4\": \"SA Western Standard Time\", \"Pacific/Wallis\": \"UTC+12\", \"Europe/Skopje\": \"Central European Standard Time\", \"America/Coral_Harbour\": \"SA Pacific Standard Time\", \"Asia/Dhaka\": \"Bangladesh Standard Time\", \"America/St_Lucia\": \"SA Western Standard Time\", \"Asia/Kashgar\": \"China Standard Time\", \"America/Phoenix\": \"US Mountain Standard Time\", \"Asia/Kuwait\": \"Arab Standard Time\" }";
```

This is the Json data I'm trying to use:

```
{"data":[{"type":"gif","id":"26gscSULUcfKU7dHq","slug":"studiosoriginals-alphabet-gilphabet-26gscSULUcfKU7dHq","url":"https:\/\/giphy.com\/gifs\/studiosoriginals-alphabet-gilphabet-26gscSULUcfKU7dHq","bitly_gif_url":"http:\/\/gph.is\/2ktry2w","bitly_url":"http:\/\/gph.is\/2ktry2w","embed_url":"https:\/\/giphy.com\/embed\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq","username":"studiosoriginals","source":"","rating":"g","content_url":"","source_tld":"","source_post_url":"","is_indexable":0,"import_datetime":"2017-02-01 22:22:47","trending_datetime":"2017-02-08 18:52:29","user":{"avatar_url":"https:\/\/media.giphy.com\/avatars\/studiosoriginals\/j3JBzK5twdv8.jpg","banner_url":"https:\/\/media.giphy.com\/headers\/studiosoriginals\/fHmcHCHkISg3.gif","profile_url":"https:\/\/giphy.com\/studiosoriginals\/","username":"studiosoriginals","display_name":"GIPHY Studios Originals","twitter":""},"images":{"fixed_height_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/200_s.gif","width":"300","height":"200","size":"6048"},"original_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/giphy_s.gif","width":"480","height":"320","size":"9780"},"fixed_width":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/200w.gif","width":"200","height":"133","size":"13081","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/200w.mp4","mp4_size":"4579","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/200w.webp","webp_size":"11096"},"fixed_height_small_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/100_s.gif","width":"150","height":"100","size":"3375"},"fixed_height_downsampled":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/200_d.gif","width":"300","height":"200","size":"23490","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/200_d.webp","webp_size":"16284"},"preview":{"width":"480","height":"320","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/giphy-preview.mp4","mp4_size":"9295"},"fixed_height_small":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/100.gif","width":"150","height":"100","size":"9207","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/100.mp4","mp4_size":"3577","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/100.webp","webp_size":"8370"},"downsized_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/giphy-downsized_s.gif","width":"480","height":"320","size":"9780"},"downsized":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/giphy-downsized.gif","width":"480","height":"320","size":"44098"},"downsized_large":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/giphy.gif","width":"480","height":"320","size":"44098"},"fixed_width_small_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/100w_s.gif","width":"100","height":"67","size":"2342"},"preview_webp":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/giphy-preview.webp","width":"480","height":"320","size":"27344"},"fixed_width_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/200w_s.gif","width":"200","height":"133","size":"4082"},"fixed_width_small":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/100w.gif","width":"100","height":"67","size":"5871","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/100w.mp4","mp4_size":"2690","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/100w.webp","webp_size":"6206"},"downsized_small":{"width":"480","height":"320","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/giphy-downsized-small.mp4","mp4_size":"9295"},"fixed_width_downsampled":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/200w_d.gif","width":"200","height":"133","size":"13081","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/200w_d.webp","webp_size":"11096"},"downsized_medium":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/giphy.gif","width":"480","height":"320","size":"44098"},"original":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/giphy.gif","width":"480","height":"320","size":"44098","frames":"6","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/giphy.mp4","mp4_size":"10969","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/giphy.webp","webp_size":"28662","hash":"fe97ee89c8223e31ed7c1ac2080aaf32"},"fixed_height":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/200.gif","width":"300","height":"200","size":"23490","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/200.mp4","mp4_size":"6847","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/200.webp","webp_size":"16284"},"looping":{"mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/giphy-loop.mp4","mp4_size":"269263"},"original_mp4":{"width":"480","height":"320","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/giphy.mp4","mp4_size":"10969"},"preview_gif":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/giphy-preview.gif","width":"480","height":"320","size":"44098"},"480w_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media4.giphy.com\/media\/26gscSULUcfKU7dHq\/480w_s.jpg","width":"480","height":"320"}}},{"type":"gif","id":"3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok","slug":"studiosoriginals-3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok","url":"https:\/\/giphy.com\/gifs\/studiosoriginals-3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok","bitly_gif_url":"http:\/\/gph.is\/2oUxRj8","bitly_url":"http:\/\/gph.is\/2oUxRj8","embed_url":"https:\/\/giphy.com\/embed\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok","username":"studiosoriginals","source":"","rating":"g","content_url":"","source_tld":"","source_post_url":"","is_indexable":0,"import_datetime":"2017-05-02 17:06:47","trending_datetime":"2017-05-02 19:24:32","user":{"avatar_url":"https:\/\/media.giphy.com\/avatars\/studiosoriginals\/j3JBzK5twdv8.jpg","banner_url":"https:\/\/media.giphy.com\/headers\/studiosoriginals\/fHmcHCHkISg3.gif","profile_url":"https:\/\/giphy.com\/studiosoriginals\/","username":"studiosoriginals","display_name":"GIPHY Studios Originals","twitter":""},"images":{"fixed_height_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/200_s.gif","width":"300","height":"200","size":"14353"},"original_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/giphy_s.gif","width":"480","height":"320","size":"21947"},"fixed_width":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/200w.gif","width":"200","height":"133","size":"14848","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/200w.mp4","mp4_size":"9628","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/200w.webp","webp_size":"11200"},"fixed_height_small_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/100_s.gif","width":"150","height":"100","size":"6137"},"fixed_height_downsampled":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/200_d.gif","width":"300","height":"200","size":"26349","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/200_d.webp","webp_size":"18452"},"preview":{"width":"480","height":"320","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/giphy-preview.mp4","mp4_size":"29150"},"fixed_height_small":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/100.gif","width":"150","height":"100","size":"10188","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/100.mp4","mp4_size":"6570","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/100.webp","webp_size":"7988"},"downsized_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/giphy-downsized_s.gif","width":"480","height":"320","size":"21947"},"downsized":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/giphy-downsized.gif","width":"480","height":"320","size":"41498"},"downsized_large":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/giphy.gif","width":"480","height":"320","size":"41498"},"fixed_width_small_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/100w_s.gif","width":"100","height":"67","size":"4321"},"preview_webp":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/giphy-preview.webp","width":"480","height":"320","size":"33904"},"fixed_width_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/200w_s.gif","width":"200","height":"133","size":"8488"},"fixed_width_small":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/100w.gif","width":"100","height":"67","size":"6568","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/100w.mp4","mp4_size":"4173","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/100w.webp","webp_size":"4910"},"downsized_small":{"width":"480","height":"320","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/giphy-downsized-small.mp4","mp4_size":"29150"},"fixed_width_downsampled":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/200w_d.gif","width":"200","height":"133","size":"14848","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/200w_d.webp","webp_size":"11200"},"downsized_medium":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/giphy.gif","width":"480","height":"320","size":"41498"},"original":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/giphy.gif","width":"480","height":"320","size":"41498","frames":"2","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/giphy.mp4","mp4_size":"29150","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/giphy.webp","webp_size":"33904","hash":"450863b9edc607baf1c6a3120a1bcb76"},"fixed_height":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/200.gif","width":"300","height":"200","size":"26349","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/200.mp4","mp4_size":"16193","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/200.webp","webp_size":"18452"},"looping":{"mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/giphy-loop.mp4","mp4_size":"2126108"},"original_mp4":{"width":"480","height":"320","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/giphy.mp4","mp4_size":"29150"},"preview_gif":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/giphy-preview.gif","width":"480","height":"320","size":"41498"},"480w_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media4.giphy.com\/media\/3oKIPnvlVTnGnFunok\/480w_s.jpg","width":"480","height":"320"}}},{"type":"gif","id":"l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu","slug":"typography-letters-caretoz-l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu","url":"https:\/\/giphy.com\/gifs\/typography-letters-caretoz-l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu","bitly_gif_url":"http:\/\/gph.is\/2dU51IJ","bitly_url":"http:\/\/gph.is\/2dU51IJ","embed_url":"https:\/\/giphy.com\/embed\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu","username":"gongif","source":"","rating":"g","content_url":"","source_tld":"","source_post_url":"","is_indexable":1,"import_datetime":"2016-10-25 22:16:09","trending_datetime":"1970-01-01 00:00:00","user":{"avatar_url":"https:\/\/media.giphy.com\/avatars\/default1.gif","banner_url":"","profile_url":"https:\/\/giphy.com\/gongif\/","username":"gongif","display_name":"Gon\u00e7alo","twitter":""},"images":{"fixed_height_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/200_s.gif","width":"200","height":"200","size":"4994"},"original_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/giphy_s.gif","width":"600","height":"600","size":"19149"},"fixed_width":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/200w.gif","width":"200","height":"200","size":"82999","mp4":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/200w.mp4","mp4_size":"13339","webp":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/200w.webp","webp_size":"145034"},"fixed_height_small_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/100_s.gif","width":"100","height":"100","size":"2628"},"fixed_height_downsampled":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/200_d.gif","width":"200","height":"200","size":"13448","webp":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/200_d.webp","webp_size":"16682"},"preview":{"width":"600","height":"600","mp4":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/giphy-preview.mp4","mp4_size":"25205"},"fixed_height_small":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/100.gif","width":"100","height":"100","size":"29666","mp4":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/100.mp4","mp4_size":"6888","webp":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/100.webp","webp_size":"62656"},"downsized_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/giphy-downsized_s.gif","width":"600","height":"600","size":"19149"},"downsized":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/giphy-downsized.gif","width":"600","height":"600","size":"458435"},"downsized_large":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/giphy.gif","width":"600","height":"600","size":"458435"},"fixed_width_small_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/100w_s.gif","width":"100","height":"100","size":"2628"},"preview_webp":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/giphy-preview.webp","width":"600","height":"600","size":"47628"},"fixed_width_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/200w_s.gif","width":"200","height":"200","size":"4994"},"fixed_width_small":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/100w.gif","width":"100","height":"100","size":"29666","mp4":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/100w.mp4","mp4_size":"6888","webp":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/100w.webp","webp_size":"62656"},"downsized_small":{"width":"600","height":"600","mp4":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/giphy-downsized-small.mp4","mp4_size":"65092"},"fixed_width_downsampled":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/200w_d.gif","width":"200","height":"200","size":"13448","webp":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/200w_d.webp","webp_size":"16682"},"downsized_medium":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/giphy.gif","width":"600","height":"600","size":"458435"},"original":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/giphy.gif","width":"600","height":"600","size":"458435","frames":"101","mp4":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/giphy.mp4","mp4_size":"33518","webp":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/giphy.webp","webp_size":"575820","hash":"23f84bcc79225f3a818e001e778b227f"},"fixed_height":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/200.gif","width":"200","height":"200","size":"82999","mp4":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/200.mp4","mp4_size":"13339","webp":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/200.webp","webp_size":"145034"},"looping":{"mp4":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/giphy-loop.mp4","mp4_size":"129966"},"original_mp4":{"width":"480","height":"480","mp4":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/giphy.mp4","mp4_size":"33518"},"preview_gif":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/giphy-preview.gif","width":"600","height":"600","size":"44725"},"480w_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media0.giphy.com\/media\/l3vR1Ie00TQSzgtxu\/480w_s.jpg","width":"480","height":"480"}}},{"type":"gif","id":"F3sHlY1SgDIgE","slug":"kiss-amor-g-F3sHlY1SgDIgE","url":"https:\/\/giphy.com\/gifs\/kiss-amor-g-F3sHlY1SgDIgE","bitly_gif_url":"http:\/\/gph.is\/1cczpGI","bitly_url":"http:\/\/gph.is\/1cczpGI","embed_url":"https:\/\/giphy.com\/embed\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE","username":"","source":"http:\/\/unicorn-infiniter.tumblr.com\/post\/70738607322","rating":"g","content_url":"","source_tld":"unicorn-infiniter.tumblr.com","source_post_url":"http:\/\/unicorn-infiniter.tumblr.com\/post\/70738607322","is_indexable":0,"import_datetime":"2013-12-22 03:14:18","trending_datetime":"1970-01-01 00:00:00","images":{"fixed_height_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/200_s.gif","width":"355","height":"200"},"original_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/giphy_s.gif","width":"500","height":"282"},"fixed_width":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/200w.gif","width":"200","height":"113","size":"62913","mp4":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/200w.mp4","mp4_size":"14144","webp":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/200w.webp","webp_size":"70578"},"fixed_height_small_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/100_s.gif","width":"177","height":"100"},"fixed_height_downsampled":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/200_d.gif","width":"355","height":"200","size":"266014","webp":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/200_d.webp","webp_size":"95814"},"preview":{"width":"400","height":"224","mp4":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/giphy-preview.mp4","mp4_size":"34348"},"fixed_height_small":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/100.gif","width":"177","height":"100","size":"152214","mp4":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/100.mp4","mp4_size":"74997","webp":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/100.webp","webp_size":"54976"},"downsized_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/giphy-downsized_s.gif","width":"500","height":"282","size":"58470"},"downsized":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/giphy-downsized.gif","width":"500","height":"282","size":"516064"},"downsized_large":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/giphy.gif","width":"500","height":"282","size":"516064"},"fixed_width_small_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/100w_s.gif","width":"100","height":"56"},"preview_webp":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/giphy-preview.webp","width":"213","height":"120","size":"49936"},"fixed_width_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/200w_s.gif","width":"200","height":"113"},"fixed_width_small":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/100w.gif","width":"100","height":"56","size":"62913","mp4":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/100w.mp4","mp4_size":"36884","webp":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/100w.webp","webp_size":"23792"},"downsized_small":{"width":"500","height":"282","mp4":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/giphy-downsized-small.mp4","mp4_size":"77827"},"fixed_width_downsampled":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/200w_d.gif","width":"200","height":"113","size":"102857","webp":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/200w_d.webp","webp_size":"38278"},"downsized_medium":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/giphy.gif","width":"500","height":"282","size":"516064"},"original":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/giphy.gif","width":"500","height":"282","size":"516064","frames":"11","mp4":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/giphy.mp4","mp4_size":"42236","webp":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/giphy.webp","webp_size":"280590"},"fixed_height":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/200.gif","width":"355","height":"200","size":"152214","mp4":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/200.mp4","mp4_size":"13182","webp":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/200.webp","webp_size":"177648"},"looping":{"mp4":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/giphy-loop.mp4","mp4_size":"4057647"},"original_mp4":{"width":"480","height":"270","mp4":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/giphy.mp4","mp4_size":"42236"},"preview_gif":{"url":"https:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/giphy-preview.gif","width":"158","height":"89","size":"48766"},"480w_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/F3sHlY1SgDIgE\/480w_s.jpg","width":"480","height":"271"}}},{"type":"gif","id":"xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2","slug":"typography-b-growths-xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2","url":"https:\/\/giphy.com\/gifs\/typography-b-growths-xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2","bitly_gif_url":"http:\/\/gph.is\/1OcHtcw","bitly_url":"http:\/\/gph.is\/1OcHtcw","embed_url":"https:\/\/giphy.com\/embed\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2","username":"ariweinkle","source":"http:\/\/ariweinkle.com","rating":"g","content_url":"","source_tld":"ariweinkle.com","source_post_url":"http:\/\/ariweinkle.com","is_indexable":0,"import_datetime":"2016-01-10 22:24:18","trending_datetime":"0001-12-30 00:00:00","user":{"avatar_url":"https:\/\/media.giphy.com\/avatars\/ariweinkle\/z0LAadW4w9Yw.png","banner_url":"","profile_url":"https:\/\/giphy.com\/ariweinkle\/","username":"ariweinkle","display_name":"Ari Weinkle","twitter":"@ariweinkle"},"images":{"fixed_height_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/200_s.gif","width":"200","height":"200"},"original_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/giphy_s.gif","width":"500","height":"500"},"fixed_width":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/200w.gif","width":"200","height":"200","size":"498632","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/200w.mp4","mp4_size":"69839","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/200w.webp","webp_size":"388366"},"fixed_height_small_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/100_s.gif","width":"100","height":"100"},"fixed_height_downsampled":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/200_d.gif","width":"200","height":"200","size":"52130","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/200_d.webp","webp_size":"39670"},"preview":{"width":"160","height":"160","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/giphy-preview.mp4","mp4_size":"41742"},"fixed_height_small":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/100.gif","width":"100","height":"100","size":"143504","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/100.mp4","mp4_size":"23824","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/100.webp","webp_size":"141682"},"downsized_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/giphy-tumblr_s.gif","width":"250","height":"250"},"downsized":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/giphy-tumblr.gif","width":"250","height":"250","size":"806400"},"downsized_large":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/giphy.gif","width":"500","height":"500","size":"3094507"},"fixed_width_small_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/100w_s.gif","width":"100","height":"100"},"preview_webp":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/giphy-preview.webp","width":"204","height":"204","size":"49322"},"fixed_width_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/200w_s.gif","width":"200","height":"200"},"fixed_width_small":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/100w.gif","width":"100","height":"100","size":"143504","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/100w.mp4","mp4_size":"23824","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/100w.webp","webp_size":"141682"},"downsized_small":{"width":"306","height":"306","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/giphy-downsized-small.mp4","mp4_size":"167406"},"fixed_width_downsampled":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/200w_d.gif","width":"200","height":"200","size":"52130","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/200w_d.webp","webp_size":"39670"},"downsized_medium":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/giphy.gif","width":"500","height":"500","size":"3094507"},"original":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/giphy.gif","width":"500","height":"500","size":"3094507","frames":"56","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/giphy.mp4","mp4_size":"341598","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/giphy.webp","webp_size":"1881390"},"fixed_height":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/200.gif","width":"200","height":"200","size":"498632","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/200.mp4","mp4_size":"69839","webp":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/200.webp","webp_size":"388366"},"looping":{"mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/giphy-loop.mp4","mp4_size":"3138038"},"original_mp4":{"width":"480","height":"480","mp4":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/giphy.mp4","mp4_size":"341598"},"preview_gif":{"url":"https:\/\/media2.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/giphy-preview.gif","width":"185","height":"185","size":"48411"},"480w_still":{"url":"https:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/xT77XJh2xnwvFsVRn2\/480w_s.jpg","width":"480","height":"480"}}}],"pagination":{"total_count":63048,"count":5,"offset":0},"meta":{"status":200,"msg":"OK","response_id":"59b3a9a04b6d6f69556ebd92"}}
151.101.38.2
```

I cannot change the Json data, because I'm getting it from a URL, but I think it goes wrong because the Json data looks different from the example Json data. How do I get the URL from this Json data?

Comment: `url` is inside data array and you´re accesing `url` on the root of the json according to the example json. Also use a class instead of Jobject, so it can deserialize it for you.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is use this tool to convert your json to a class:
http://json2csharp.com/

Once you've done this, you can use the Newtonsoft library that you are already using to convert the json in to a typed object from your class like this:

```
var object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassName>(json);
```

Once you have done this, you can use the ImageUrl from the object to download the image.You can now use WebClient in Xamarin which is probably the best way to download an image. You can see a post about it here:

[How to download image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797485/how-to-download-image-from-url/24797679)

I'm not sure what your GetGiphyImageUrl method does, but this is how you can load the data in to an Image control:

```
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    bytes = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(Url);

                    Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes));
                }
```