# Unable to download the image using c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to download the image from azure blob storage using the below code

```
      String fullPath;
        fullPath = path + names[0];
        FileStream fileStreamInput = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        FileStreamResult fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(fileStreamInput, "APPLICATION/octet-stream");
        if (names == null || names.Length == 0)
            fileStreamResult.FileDownloadName = fileStreamInput.Name;
        else fileStreamResult.FileDownloadName = names[0];
        return fileStreamResult;
```

Here, value for full path was received as https://mycustomazure.blob.core.windows.net/blob1/

names[0] is user.png

But i got the exception The given path's format is not supported
 [image]

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: What do you have in the variable `fullPath`?

Comment: https://mycustomazure.blob.core.windows.net/blob1/content/user.png

Comment: I guess that would mean that the FileStream expects a path starting with Drive:\. To download from a website try using the HttpClient

Comment: Use the Azure client: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#access-the-file-share-programmatically

Comment: I am using it in asp.net core frame work

Comment: It is .Net Standard 1.0 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx

I don't see a single instance where it says you can use web path to initialise a new FileStream.

Download the file first to local disk and then initialise with local file.

Answer (score 0):

FileStream not allow get image from web.
You should use `WebClient` class. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797485/how-to-download-image-from-url-using-c-sharp), how you can get image from web