# Why do I get an exception when using WebClient.DownloadData for a url?

Tags: c#, webclient

I have 2 urls:

https://static.summitracing.com/global/images/prod/xlarge/cse-5160_xl.jpg
http://www.americanbassusa.com/Subwoofers/DX-Series-Images/DX/DX-front.jpg

Both download the corresponding images correctly when opened in Chrome but when using the following console application to download them using [WebClient.DownloadData(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddata?view=netframework-4.8), the second url causes a [System.Net.WebException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webexception?view=netframework-4.8) to be thrown.

Can any one provide me with an understanding as to why this is happening?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string WorkingUrl = "https://static.summitracing.com/global/images/prod/xlarge/cse-5160_xl.jpg";
        const string NonWorkingUrl = "http://www.americanbassusa.com/Subwoofers/DX-Series-Images/DX/DX-front.jpg";

        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                byte[] fileData = client.DownloadData(NonWorkingUrl);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The exception details are:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(String address)
   at ConsoleApp4.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\\Users\\davidandrewpowell\\source\\repos\\ConsoleApp4\\ConsoleApp4\\Program.cs:line 17
```

Comment: Please paste the exception details into your question, A `WebException` can be anything

Comment: What's the actual error message inside the exception though?

Comment: Apologies, I have added the exception message to the question.

Comment: A 400 just means that the server software thought your request was invalid. It's up to the server software to determine that, so each site is different. Maybe your request is missing headers or has a bad user-agent string, maybe it's something else, who knows?

Comment: You might want to use [`DownloadFile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797485/how-to-download-image-from-url) rather than `DownloadData`.

Comment: Thanks Caius Jard.  Thats a good tip.  I'll try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular server wants a useragent string that indicates a browser is in use. This works:

```
    using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
             client.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134");
             client.DownloadFile(NonWorkingUrl, "c:\\temp\\a");
        }
    }
```

No particular reason I used downloadfile- just playing around with stuff. If you need the byte array in your app then surely use downloaddata :)

Comment: That's great.  Thanks for your help.