# How to loop through a specific column of Excel worksheet and download it in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am working on a small project and need some quick help here. I have an excel worksheet with following fields,

**Id, Name, Image**

I want to grab only the **Image** and loop through all the image rows and extract its data into an Excel sheet

Is this possible somehow?

I have this:
**Edit**
I have a button on which I am uploading one Excel file, and there is only one excel file. This file has a column named Image which has some url.  Now, when I upload an Excel file, I want to download the image from url mentioned in Excel file and update the url in it.

```
var excel = new ExcelPackage(FileUpload2.FileContent);
var dta = excel.ToDataTable();
DataView view = new DataView(dta);
DataTable dt = view.ToTable("Id","Name","Image");
for(int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
   for(int j = 0; j <= dt.Columns.Count; j++)
   {
         // what to write here??                
   }
 }
```

I am using **OfficeOpenXML** for my excel operations.

Comment: How to download image from url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797485/how-to-download-image-from-url

Comment: Thanks @RobinBennett , but I am looking to download the image from excel sheet by looping through the columns. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: It looks like you can already open the file and loop through the columns, so what is the immediate problem? Getting the value of one cell?

Comment: @RobinBennett, All I want is I want to download the image file on local machine grabbing the url of that image from excel sheet.

Comment: I know, but there are several steps to that and I don't know which bit is the problem.

Comment: @RobinBennett you can check my edit