# How to save image via url from xml file C#

Tags: c#, c, asp.net, .net, system.drawing

I am a newbie for c# I want to know how I download images by URL in my XML file.
Now, I am writing the code for reading XML

```
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(pathXml))
            {
                while (xmlReader.Read())
                {
                    if (xmlReader.IsStartElement())
                    {
                        switch (xmlReader.Name)
                        {
                            
                            case "id":
                                string id = xmlReader.ReadString();
                                Console.WriteLine("id "+id);
                                break;
                            case "url":
                                string url = xmlReader.ReadString();
                                Console.WriteLine("url "+url);
                                break;
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
```

Add more detail after trying to do but
I am stuck again

```
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    
                    using (var yourImage = Image.FromStream(mem))
                    {
                        yourImage.Save("Image2.png", ImageFormat.Png);
                    }
                }
```

in line using(var yourImage = Image.FromStream(mem))
it's show Exception Unhandled
System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid'
What should I do ?? Please help me

FYI: the URL in data is an image without format in Website that must be log-in user and password

Comment: What is in URL? Its Physical Path of file in your local computer?

Comment: Its a simple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c

Comment: @Jasmin Solanki
It an address of an image like this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/VAN_CAT.png but it's doesn't have .png. I can click the link to open it immediately

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797485/how-to-download-image-from-url Can you check this it may be helpful to you