# Invoke-RestMethod throwing forbidden error 403 while trying to access Power BI

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powerbi

I am connecting to the Power Bi using the service principle like below.

```
$PbiSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $ClientSecret -Force -AsPlainText
$PbiCredential = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential($ClientId, $PbiSecurePassword)
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $PbiCredential
$headers = Get-PowerBIAccessToken
```

Then I am trying to update the dataset values like below

```
$datasourePostUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/$workspaceId/datasets/$datasetId/Default.UpdateDatasources"
# create HTTP request body to update datasource connection details
$postBody = @{
  "updateDetails" = @(
   @{
    "connectionDetails" = @{
      "server" = "$dbserver"
      "database" = "$dbname"
    }
    "datasourceSelector" = @{
      "datasourceType" = "Sql"
      "connectionDetails" = @{
        "server" = "$sqlDatabaseServerCurrent"
        "database" = "$sqlDatabaseNameCurrent"
      }
      "gatewayId" = "$gatewayId"
      "datasourceId" = "$datasourceId"
    }
  })
}

# convert body contents to JSON
$postBodyJson = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $postBody -Depth 6 -Compress

#Added UseDefaultCredentials & UserAgent based on the stack overflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735376/6862041 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/27882588/6862041
$userAgent = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::Chrome

# execute POST operation to update datasource connection details
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Method Post -Uri $datasourePostUrl -UserAgent $userAgent -UseDefaultCredentials -Body $postBodyJson -ContentType $ContentType
```

I am getting the following error

```
Exception        : System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
 at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
ErrorCategory    : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
```

Not sure what I am missing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 403 error would suggest that user credentials are correct, but the user that you're connecting as doesn't have access rights to update data source connection.

Comment: I have created this service principle in Azure Ad and given the permissions to this Power Bi workspace. This is working when I am trying to embed it into my web app. But it's not working when I am trying to build a CI/CD with the same Service principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the service principal is having necessary perms at Workspace/dataset.

There could be a setting (Allow Service Principals to use Power BI APIs.
) at the tenant level which could be causing the error - if the setting is in the disabled state - you re likely to encounter this behavior.

**Note :**  This is in **disabled** state by Default.

You will have to access the below as an **Power BI  service Admin**

Power BI Admin Portal --> Tenant Settings --> Developer Settings --> Allow Service Principals to use Power BI APIs.

[image]

Toggle it to Enabled state.

You can either enable this feature to the entire org or to specific set of Service Principal belonging to a Security Group.

Click 'Apply'.

Comment: @joseph - Did the above step help you ?